# Using an array with the Switch command?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to process all the potential incoming parameters of a veridic function. I use the general "Switch" command in other languages for these kinds scenarios.
But I cant quite figure it out in AHK though.

---

## Code:

I have in mind something like the following, where I can handle each of the elements on a case by case basis.

```
Array :=  ["One", "Two", "three"]
switch  Array
    {
        Case  "One": 
            OutputDebug, % "One"
        Case "Two":
        OutputDebug, % "Two"
        Case "Three":
        OutputDebug, % "Three"
    }
```

If you are thinking why no just use a loop? Because the handling I require for each parameter is different from one parameter to the next, One parameter could require 15 lines to process while another just 1.

---

## Desired Output:

```
    MyFunc(Param*){
    switch  Param
        {
            Case "two":
            OutputDebug, % "two"
            Case "Three":
            OutputDebug, % "Three"
            Case  "one": 
                OutputDebug, % "one"
        }
    }
MyFun("One", "Two", "Three")
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to execute n amount of different code blocks based on what arguments are passed into a function? Like you call `MyFun("one")` code block for `"one"` is executed, but you call `MyFun("one", "two")`, code blocks for both `"one"` and `"two"` are executed? If so, you'd just loop over all the arguments that are passed into the function, and your switch case would be inside the loop.

Comment: @0x464e Yup! you are right. Someone else proposed the same solution as you on another forum. Thanks!